# Why is my MultiAdapter failing to register?

Tags: python, zope, zope.component

I'm currently experimenting with the ZCA and I've run into a bit of a hitch.  The script below defines an `IFuncttion` interface, which is used to create function objects that can be chained (i.e. monads).

In this example, I'm trying to create a simple writer monad as an adapter, but `getMultiAdapter` is raising a `ComponentLookupError`.  Why is this?

```
from zope import component, interface


class IFunction(interface.Interface):
    name = interface.Attribute('Name of the function object')

    def __call__(*args, **kw):
        """Call the function"""


class Function(object):
    name = ''
    interface.implements(IFunction)

    def __call__(self, *args, **kw):
        return self.run(*args, **kw)

    def run(self, *args, **kw):
        raise NotImplementedError


class MWriter(object):
    component.adapts(IFunction, IFunction)
    interface.implements(IFunction)

    def __init__(self, prv, nxt):
        self.prev, self.next = prv, nxt

    def bind(self, x, log=None):
        log = log or []
        result, line = self.prev(x)
        log.append(line)
        return self.next(result, log)

    def __call__(self, *args, **kw):
        return self.bind(*args, **kw)


class AddOne(Function):
    name = 'addone'

    def run(self, x):
        return x + 1


class MulTwo(Function):
    name = 'multwo'

    def run(self, x):
        return x * 2

component.provideAdapter(MWriter)
print component.getMultiAdapter((AddOne(), MulTwo()), MWriter)(11, [])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should *not* pass in the adapter you want to look up to `component.getMultiAdapter()`. The second argument to that function is the *name* used for named adapters, but your registration did not use a name.

Simply remove that second argument:

```
>>> component.getMultiAdapter((AddOne(), MulTwo()))
<__main__.MWriter object at 0x1072516d0>
```

Unfortunately, *calling* `MWriter()` still fails because you expect `self.prev()` to return a tuple:

```
result, line = self.prev(x)
```

but `AddOne()` returns just the one integer:

```
class AddOne(Function):
    name = 'addone'

    def run(self, x):
        return x + 1
```

so you get an exception:

```
>>> component.getMultiAdapter((AddOne(), MulTwo()))(11)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 37, in __call__
  File "<string>", line 32, in bind
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Perhaps you wanted each `Function()` to return the name as well as the result:

```
class Function(object):
    name = ''
    interface.implements(IFunction)

    def __call__(self, *args, **kw):
        return self.run(*args, **kw), self.name

    def run(self, *args, **kw):
        raise NotImplementedError
```

but then calling `self.next()` fails because it doesn't accept the extra `log` argument passed in.